# How to store a networkx graph for visualizing in Gephi?

Tags: python, networkx, gephi, graph-visualization

I am working on a pagerank algorithm using Networkx module in Python. I have a dictionary of lists, where key of the dictionary is the Title of the page and its value is all the Titles referenced through that page.

So in order to create a visualization, I first did this:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G = nx.from_dict_of_lists(ref_dict)
```

where `ref_dict` is the dictionary mentioned above.

After creating the graph, I am using Networkx's `write_edgelist` function to store the Graph in the csv format.

```
nx.write_edgelist(subG,'PageRanks2.csv')
```

Herein lies my problem. The csv file is storing edges as:

node1 node2 {}
node1 node3 {}

When I am using this file directly in Gephi, it treats the {} as a node and shows visualization accordingly. 
So what should be the best format to store the networkx graph to visualize it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `write_gexf` function like: `nx.write_gexf(G, "test.gexf")`,
and open the file using `Gephi`, then you'll see it.

Reference https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.gexf.write_gexf.html#write-gexf

Answer (score 3):

You can specify `data` argument to tell networkx not to add `{}`:

```
nx.write_edgelist(subG,'PageRanks2.csv', data=False)
```

There are other formats which both networkx and Gephi support (e.g. GraphML), and you can accomplish much more complex data visualization tasks if your data has attributes associated with it.